Sudoku solver using backtracking
I am using this code to solve sudoku using backtracking algorithm but it, although giving right answer, is encountering the error of "memory limit exceeded" where I am trying to test it
I think I am trapped in a loop somewhere!
import numpy as np

def sudoku_solver_util(mat, many, f_count):
    if many[0] >= 9 ** (81 - f_count):
        return False
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if mat[i][j] == 0:
                counter = 0
                for k in range(1, 10):
                    counter += 1
                    many[0] += 1
                    if is_safe(mat, i, j, k, 0, f_count, many):
                        mat[i][j] = k
                        if sudoku_solver_util(mat, many, f_count):
                            return True
                        count = np.count_nonzero(mat)
                        if many[0] >= 9**(81-f_count):
                            return False
                        mat[i][j] = 0
                    if counter == 9:
                        return False
    return True

def row_is_safe(mat, i, j, k):
    return not k in mat[i][:]

def col_is_safe(mat, i, j, k):
    return not k in mat[:,j]

def grid_is_safe(mat, i, j, k):
    return not k in small_sudoku(mat, i, j)

def is_safe(mat, i, j, k, counter, count, many):
    return row_is_safe(mat, i, j, k) and col_is_safe(mat, i, j, k) and grid_is_safe(mat, i, j, k)

def small_sudoku(mat, i, j):
    return mat[(i//3)*3:(i//3)*3+3, (j//3)*3:(j//3)*3+3]

def sudoku_solver(mat):
    many = [0]
    f_count = np.count_nonzero(mat)
    if sudoku_solver_util(mat, many, f_count):
        return mat
    else:
        return np.zeros((9,9))

# input
mat = np.zeros((9,9))
for i in range(0,9):
    mat[i] = list(map(int, input().split()))

# output
out_mat = sudoku_solver(mat)
for row in out_mat:
    print(" ".join(map(str, row.astype(int))))


you can format your code using these guidelines, it'd be more readable : https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Provide some hard-coded input.  This code requires input() but we don't know what it looks like.

FYI, I hard-coded a 9x9 np.array as input and your code solved the puzzle with no error, so seeing your input that causes you a problem is crucial.  Also, how much memory do you have?  Your recursion could be too complicated.   What's the specific error message (full traceback)?

There's a very large chance that the python recursion depth limit (1000) has been exceeded. Are you submitting this code to an online judging system?
